# TikZ Coordinate calculation - calculate coordinates separately

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I'm trying to calculate coordinates based on existing coordinates but each coordinate individually.

The first thing which is unclear to me is how to define scalar variables. I can define coordinates using the `\coordinate` command, but what about scalars?

Looking through the manual I found the `\pgfextractx` command, but I don't know how to use it, is it possible to use it within a coordinate calculation like for example

```
\coordinate(blah) at ($ (\pgfextractx{(centre)} + 2*cos(30), .. )$)
```

?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "calculate coordinates based on existing coordinates but each coordinate individually"? I have the feeling you use "coordinate" for both `\coordinate` and the X and Y part of it, which makes the question quite difficult to read.

Comment: Agree this was somewhat confusing, I just want to access the x and y part of it separately instead of, let's say just multiply the coordinate vector with a scalar.

Comment: You could define scalars with `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do by means of `let` operation:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue] (0,0) coordinate (centre) circle[radius=1pt];
    \fill[red] let \p1=(centre) in
        ({\x1 + 2 * cos(30)}, \y1) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this radius. (line 7)

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `\pgfmathresult` inside a coordinate. This macro is overwritten by any `pgfmath` operation. It is much saver to use `\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{...}` instead of `\pgfmathparse{...}` and then `\myresult pt` as X-coordinate. Note that `\pgfmathresult` is in `pt` but without the unit, so just using it alone will give you wrong results except when `x=1pt` is in affect.

Comment: @Nils: it turns out that we use different versions of PGF (I use v2.10).

Comment: @Martin: Thank you for your comment, I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Nils: with v2.00 you have to write `... circle (1pt)` instead of `... circle [radius=1pt]`.

Comment: @Dmitry: One can simply write `({\x1 + 2 * cos(30)}, \y1)`. (Note the additional braces and that `\x1` already contains the unit pt.)

Comment: @Caramdir: wow, that's awesome! Could you point me out where the manual introduces such syntax?

Comment: No idea where that is explained (if at all). I think I picked it up from the plot example on page 225 (v2.10). Generally in TikZ, if it refuses to parse something as math, then try putting it in braces.